# What is the correct way of implementing the heapsort?

Tags: java, algorithm, heapsort

I spend last 5 hours looking at so many videos and readings (cormen included) and i finally decided to write my own heapsort to test it out. I am basically taking some inputs from standard input and storing them in an array and then i will use heapsort to sort them.

Following is my code

```
 public static void buildHeap(int[] A)
     {
         n = A.length - 1;
         for(int i = n/2; i>0; i--)
         {
             maxHeapify(A,i);
         }
     }

     public static void maxHeapify(int[] A, int i)
     {
         int left = 2*i;
         int right = 2*i + 1;
         int largest = 0;
         if(left <= n && A[left] > A[i])
            {
                largest=left;
            }
            else
            {
                largest=i;
            }

            if(right <= n && A[right] > A[largest]){
                largest=right;
            }
            if(largest!=i){
                int temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[largest];
                A[largest] = temp;
                maxHeapify(A, largest);
            }
        }
```

> My Array Input is : 3,5,8,7,1,13,11,15,6 Output is:
>   3,15,13,11,6,8,5,7,1

The output is obviously wrong as the first index should contain the highest value 15.

So then i decided to take the good old route of taking a pen and a notebook and tracing the code and realized that in the buildHeap the i should be n-1/2 . However it also did not give me the correct output. I am really lost now and frustrated. Can anyone shed light as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the ideal output?

Comment: Well one thing for sure is that 15 should be in the first index in the output but it is not....so i am definitely messing up somewhere.

Comment: Where is the rest of your heapsort code?

Comment: @immibis i would need one more function to do final sorting but i can't go there because my heap is not being build correctly. so i am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index calculations are off:

```
int left = 2*i;
int right = 2*i + 1;
```

If `i` is 0, then we want `left` and `right` to be 1 and 2. If `i` is 1, then `left` and `right` should be 3 and 4, and so on. The calculations should be:

```
int left = 2*i + 1;
int right = 2*i + 2;
```

Also,

```
for(int i = n/2; i>0; i--)
```

The condition is `i > 0`. The body of the loop will only run when `i > 0`, so the element at index 0 (i.e. the first one) won't get moved. The condition should be `i >= 0`.

Comment: Also i had a question, do you think n/2 is correct or should it be n-1/2 ?

Comment: Actually it looks like it should be `(n-2)/2`. It's not hurting anything to check more though, apart from a very very slight amount of performance.

Comment: wait why are you saying its n-2 don't you mean n-1 instead?

Comment: Actually I did mean n-2. Try a few examples, by drawing diagrams: if you have 15 elements, then the first 7 nodes (highest index 6) have children, and the last 8 are leaf nodes. The highest index of a non-leaf node is `(15 - 2) / 2 == 6`. If you have 14 elements, then the first 7 nodes (highest index 6) have children, and the last 7 are leaves. `(14 - 2) / 2 == 6`. If you have 13 elements, then the first 6 have children and the last 7 are leaves (draw a diagram if you want). `(13 - 2) / 2 == 5`.

Comment: Although I didn't notice that `(n-2)/2` gives the same result as `n/2 - 1`, so you should probably use that instead.

Comment: You're right i just traced an example. Thanks a ton.